# how to counting white pixels in every rectangle in over image?

Tags: numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-preprocessing

I have thousands of images 1000X2000 px and I want count only white pixels in each small windows of image 100X200 and write  count number in vector array
please how can I do that by python openCV?

Sample Image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opencv and Numpy are pretty good at this. You can use numpy slicing to target each box and numpy.sum to count the number of white pixels in the slice.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# count white pixels per box
def boxCount(img, bw, bh):
    # declare output list
    counts = [];
    h, w = img.shape[:2];
    for y in range(0, h - bh + 1, bh):
        line = [];
        for x in range(0, w - bw + 1, bw):
            # slice out box
            box = img[y:y+bh, x:x+bw];

            # count
            count = np.sum(box == 255);
            line.append(count);
        counts.append(line);
    return counts;


# load image
img = cv2.imread("jump.png");
img = cv2.resize(img, (1000, 2000));
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

# define box search params
box_width = 100;
box_height = 200;

# get counts
counts = boxCount(img, box_width, box_height);
for line in counts:
    print(line);
```

Comment: Besides count = np.sum(box == 255), another way is:
count = len(cv2.findNonZero(box)), it will work either for "max white" and for other shades.